# Como puedo monitorizar un proceso java que se cierra sin razón aparente?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, aws

buen día. Tengo un proceso java (Spring Boot) corriendo en un servidor AWS el cual se sierra sin dejar rastro alguno y siempre a las misma hora (19:05), verifique el log y no encuentro absolutamente nada, también pensé que podía ser que el aws se reiniciara pero al parecer tampoco es el caso. Un detalle extra es que están 2 servicios de spring boot pero con diferentes dependencias y al parecer el primero no se detiene, solo el segundo.

Sistema operativo: Linux 2 AMI

El proceso se lanza desde un "java -jar"

Las dependencias que usa el servicio son muy simples:

```
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
          <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
          <version>7.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20200518</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Si ayuda en algo adjunto el archivo que ocupo para generar los logs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p ${PID:- } --- [%-40.40logger{39}]: %X{REQUEST_ID} %msg%n</Property>
        <property name="api.name">${bundle:application:configuration.api.name}</property> 
        <property name="dir.home">${bundle:application:configuration.api.home}</property> 
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>
  
        <RollingFile name="file"
            fileName="${dir.home}/${api.name}/Log/${api.name}.log"
            filePattern="${dir.home}/${api.name}/Log/$${date:yyyy-MM}/${api.name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy /><!-- Rotated everyday -->
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="file" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: ¿Se cierra sólo el proceso o todo el contenedor Java? Necesitaríamos mas información para poder decirte exactamente dónde/qué buscar, comenzando por el sistema operativo y contenedor Java.

Comment: Se cierra el proceso java, en si solo lanzo el proceso desde el comando "java -jar ", el sistema operativo es Linux 2 AMI

Comment: Revisa los mensajes de `/var/log/message` a la hora en que se cierra.

Comment: Lo único que encuentro entre esas horas es lo siguiente: 
Dec 29 19:02:16 dhclient[2833]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 120910ms.
Dec 29 19:04:17 dhclient[2833]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 128150ms.
Dec 29 19:06:26 dhclient[2833]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 112830ms.

Comment: Dependiendo de la JDK que utilices Oracle JDK8+ o OpenJDK 11+ si mal no recuerdo, puedes hacer un a Java Flight Recorder para grabar lo que esta sucediendo en la JVM antes de fallar, puedes iniciarlo unos minutos antes  ya que las grabaciones consumen mucha memoria y agrega carga a la JVM.